# apiRTC with multi page Ionic 3 app not working when navigated away from page and coming back to call page

Tags: angularjs, webrtc, ionic3

Issue replication steps:

- Click on “Click Me” button to navigate to call page.
- After apiRTC initialized you should get you call ID
- Click on back button to navigate to root page.
- Click again on “Click Me” button to navigate to call page After
  apiRTC initialized you should get you call ID but this time it will
  not work.

[Code](https://github.com/ashaqmir/ApiRTC-ionic3.git)

Comment: We should not answer questions without a [mcve] in the question body itself. Please [edit] your post and add your code here. For more details, read [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend You to initialize apirtc and all its components in a provider and call the initializer in app.componen.ts when the app starts and platform is ready, so that you will be able to access to the same client whenever you are navigating between views.